# Is it possible that I can use React Routes without a server running

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

Currently I am using BrowserHistory for my Routing in React which I need to run a nodejs server for it and I dont want to.
Are there any alternative from using BrowserHistory, I have heard of HashHistory, could anyone give me some example of hashHIstory and what is the difference between.

For me I dont care if the url looks ugly, I just dont wanna run a server only for routing.

My current code looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import Main from './components/main/main.component';
import SecondView from './components/secondview/secondview.component';
import ThirdView from './components/thirdview/thirdview.component';
import Traineeship from './components/traineeship/traineeships.component';
import InformationFilter from "./components/information/information-filter.component";

const AppRoutes = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Main}/>
            <Route path='/secondview' component={SecondView}/>
            <Route path='/traineeships' component={Traineeship}/>
            <Route path='/information-filter' component={InformationFilter}/>
            <Route path='/thirdview/:number?' component={ThirdView}/>
            <Redirect from='*' to='/' />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>

);

export default AppRoutes;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the Hash-bang mode, by utilising `HashRouter`

so, in your case, I think you just need to replace `BrowserRouter` with `HashRouter`

```
import React from "react";
import {HashRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import Main from './components/main/main.component';
import SecondView from './components/secondview/secondview.component';
import ThirdView from './components/thirdview/thirdview.component';
import Traineeship from './components/traineeship/traineeships.component';
import InformationFilter from "./components/information/information-filter.component";

const AppRoutes = () => (
    <HashRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Main}/>
            <Route path='/secondview' component={SecondView}/>
            <Route path='/traineeships' component={Traineeship}/>
            <Route path='/information-filter' component={InformationFilter}/>
            <Route path='/thirdview/:number?' component={ThirdView}/>
            <Redirect from='*' to='/' />
        </Switch>
    </HashRouter>

);

export default AppRoutes;
```

Comment: thanks, this is working! I wonder why ppl downvoted this answer!

Comment: anyhow I will mark this answer as it is working no matter what :) unless someone gives an clear explanation why this is a bad idea!

Comment: that's how it works. you can look at the official docs  at https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter and https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter